# Unable to install kubernetes charts on specified namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have installed a cluster on Google Kubernetes Engine.

And then, I created namespace "staging"

```
$ kubectl get namespaces
default       Active    26m
kube-public   Active    26m
kube-system   Active    26m
staging       Active    20m
```

Then, I switched to operate in the staging namespace

```
$ kubectl config use-context staging
$ kubectl config current-context
staging
```

And then, I installed postgresql using helm on staging namespace

```
helm install --name staging stable/postgresql
```

But I got:

> Error: release staging failed: namespaces "staging" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot get namespaces in the namespace "staging": Unknown user "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default"

What does it mean..?? How to get it working..??

Thank youu..

Comment: Can you update your post with `kubectl config get-contexts` this information

Comment: Your tiller pod do not have permission to get namespace. You need to update your Role used in toiler pod

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As your cluster is RBAC enabled, seems like your `tiller` Pod do not have enough permission.

You are using `default` ServiceAccount which lacks enough RBAC permission, tiller requires.

All you need to create ClusterRole, ClusterRoleBinding and ServiceAccount. With them you can provide necessary permission to your Pod.

Follow this steps

_1. Create ClusterRole `tiller`

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: tiller
rules:
- apiGroups: ["*"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
```

> Note: I have used full permission here.

_2. Create ServiceAccount `tiller` in `kube-system` namespace

```
$ kubectl create sa tiller -n kube-system
```

_3. Create ClusterRoleBinding `tiller`

```
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: tiller
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: tiller
  namespace: kube-system
  apiGroup: ""
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: tiller
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Now you need to use this ServiceAccount in your tiller Deployment.

As you already have one, edit that

```
$ kubectl edit deployment -n kube-system tiller-deploy
```

Set `serviceAccountName` to `tiller` under PodSpec

Read more about [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/)

Comment: Thanks! This is the only solution to the _User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot get namespaces in the namespace problem_ that I've had, that works. For future readers, when @aerokite writes about creating ClusterRole tiller and ClusterRoleBinding tiller, copy and paste his yaml to two different files, and then call `kubectl create -f <the filename>` on each of them

Comment: I could not figure out the editing of the deployment of tiller-deploy section, as I could not find the serviceAccountName under PodSpec.  I did find `helm init --upgrade --service-account tiller` on the https://docs.bitnami.com/azure/get-started-aks/ webpage and that seems to have fixed the last problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> ```
> helm init --upgrade --service-account tiller
> ```

as suggested by Scott S in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48556971#comment96368153_48557888) comment.