# How to deploy to a Kubernetes Cluster on Google Cloud using a managed DBMS on Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: kubernetes, api-platform.com, kubernetes-helm

According to the documentation found [here](https://api-platform.com/docs/deployment/kubernetes), I followed these steps:

1. Created and Published the 3 Docker images by building them and publishing them correctly to my Docker registry on Google Container Registry
2. Created a Kubernetes clusters with 3 nodes on Google Cloud Platform
3. Created a SQL Instance on Google Cloud Platform using PostgreSQL Version 9.6
4. Installed locally Kubernetes `gcloud components install kubectl`
5. Run `helm .api/helm/api update`

At the end, I run locally this command and get the following error:

```
helm install --name api ./api/helm/api \
    --set php.repository=eu.gcr.io/my_projet_id/php \
    --set nginx.repository=eu.gcr.io/my_project_id/nginx \
    --set secret=mySecret \
    --set postgresql.postgresPassword=myPostgresPassword \
    --set postgresql.persistence.enabled=true \
    --set corsAllowUrl='^https?://[a-z\]*\.my-domain.io$' \
    --set postgresql.enabled=false \
    --set postgresql.url=pgsql://my_db_user:my_db_user_password@ip_sql_instance/my_db_name?serverVersion=9.6


Error: release api failed: namespaces "default" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot get namespaces in the namespace "default": Unknown user "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default"
```

When I run `kubectl get nodes` I got a list with the 3 default nodes created by Google Cloud Platform when I created the cluster.

Am I executing the right `helm install` command?

Which namespace should I use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install kubernetes charts on specified namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48556971/unable-to-install-kubernetes-charts-on-specified-namespace)