# Not able to create Prometheus in K8S cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cloud, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to install Prometheus on my K8S cluster

when I run command

```
kubectl get namespaces
```

I got the following namespace:

```
default       Active   26h
kube-public   Active   26h
kube-system   Active   26h
monitoring    Active   153m
prod          Active   5h49m
```

Now I want to create the Prometheus via

```
helm install stable/prometheus --name prom -f k8s-values.yml
```

and I got **error:**

> Error: release prom-demo failed: namespaces "default" is forbidden:
>   User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot get resource
>   "namespaces" in API group "" in the namespace "default"

even if I switch to  `monitoring` ns I got the same error,

the k8s-values.yml look like following

```
rbac:
  create: false
server:
  name: server

  service:
    nodePort: 30002
    type: NodePort
```

Any idea what could be missing here ?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48556971/unable-to-install-kubernetes-charts-on-specified-namespace?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are using RBAC without giving the right permissions.

**Give the tiller permissions:**
*taken from https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/rbac.md*

Example: Service account with cluster-admin role
In rbac-config.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: tiller
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: tiller
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: tiller
    namespace: kube-system
```

*Note: The cluster-admin role is created by default in a Kubernetes cluster, so you don't have to define it explicitly.*

```
$ kubectl create -f rbac-config.yaml
serviceaccount "tiller" created
clusterrolebinding "tiller" created
$ helm init --service-account tiller
```

**Create a service account for prometheus:**

Change the value of `rbac.create` to `true`:

```
rbac:
  create: true
server:
  name: server

  service:
    nodePort: 30002
    type: NodePort
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now when I try to create it  (the last yaml)  I got error for missing `Kind` and `apiVersion` , I try to use service without success, any idea?

Comment: Jenny use the guide that @rom provided :
https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/rbac.md

Comment: im not able to create the service account with the yaml above , do I miss anything?

Comment: the first line in the yaml file was missing: `apiVersion: v1`, add it and try again

Comment: Please see if you can assist also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54535869/use-prometheus-with-external-ip-address

Answer (score 0):

Look at prometheus operator to spin up all monitoring services from prometheus stack.
below link is helpful
https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/tree/master/contrib/kube-prometheus/manifests

all the manifests are listed there. go through those files and deploy whatever you need to monitor in your k8s cluster