# use prometheus with external ip address

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

we have k8s cluster and I’ve application which is running there.
Now I try to add https://prometheus.io/
and I use the command

`helm install stable/prometheus --version 6.7.4 --name my-prometheus`

this command works and I got this

`NAME:   my-prometheus
LAST DEPLOYED: Tue Feb  5 15:21:46 2019
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: DEPLOYED
...`

when I run command

`kubectl get services`

I got this

```
kubernetes                         ClusterIP   100.64.0.1       <none>        443/TCP    2d4h
my-prometheus-alertmanager         ClusterIP   100.75.244.55   <none>        80/TCP     8m44s
my-prometheus-kube-state-metrics   ClusterIP   None             <none>        80/TCP     8m43s
my-prometheus-node-exporter        ClusterIP   None             <none>        9100/TCP   8m43s
my-prometheus-pushgateway          ClusterIP   100.75.24.67     <none>        9091/TCP   8m43s
my-prometheus-server               ClusterIP   100.33.26.206   <none>        80/TCP     8m43s
```

I didnt get any externalIP

Does someone knows how to add it ?  via service? any example for this

**update**

i’ve added the following yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: prometheus-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: prometheus-server
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 8080
      targetPort: 9090
      nodePort: 30001
```

which created successfully

now I see the external ip like when running kubectl get services

```
my-prometheus-server               LoadBalancer   100.33.26.206   8080:30001/TCP     80/TCP     8m43s
```

And I use in the browser 100.33.26.206:30001 and nothing happen, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is to create a service with a type LoadBalancer, those have an internal and external IP.

You can create one like any other service but you should precise those two fields:

```
externalTrafficPolicy: Local
type: LoadBalancer
```

**Updated**:

There seems to be some confusion, you don't need an external ip to monitor your apps, it will only be used to access prometheus UI.

The UI is accessible on port 9090 but prometheus is never accessed by the exporter as it will be prometheus wich will be **scraping** the exporters.

Now to access a service from the internet you should have a google ip, but it seems that what you have is still an internal IP, it's in the same subnet as the other clusterIP, and it should not. For now in place of an external ip it's showing a port redirect wich is also wrong as the prometheus UI is on port 9090 (if you didn't modify your configuration it should still be). You should try to remove the "nodePort" and leave the port redirect to kubernetes.

Comment: Thanks, but how should I connect this to Prometheus? can you please add the full yml file?

Comment: If you have a service, that should be the case as it's created, just add those lines in the specs at the same level the port is

Comment: Please see my update :) maybe you can assist, I was able to create the externalIP but when using it in the browser I dont get Prometheus dashboard

Comment: Ok what ingress configuration do you use?

Comment: I dont use ingress yet, is it a must here ?

Answer (score 1):

The Prometheus helm chart does support configuration for service, see the [documentation](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus)

To configure Prometheus server on a local cluster, follow the steps:

Create values.yaml:

```
server:
  service:
    servicePort: 31000
    type: LoadBalancer
    loadBalancerIP: localhost
```

or

```
server:
  service:
    nodePort: 31000
    type: NodePort
```

Add stable repo to helm (if missing):

```
helm repo add stable "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/"
```

Install Prometheus:

```
helm install prometheus-demo stable/prometheus --values .\values.yaml
```

Wait for 1-2mins. Prometheus should be available: http://localhost:31000/