# helm install failing on GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I am a total GCP Newbie- just created a new account.
I have installed a GKE cluster - it is active, also downloaded the sdk.
I was able to deploy a pod on GKE using kubectl.
Have tiller and helm client installed.
From the CLI when I try running a `helm` command

```
>helm install --name testngn ./nginx-test


 Error: release testngn failed: namespaces "default" is forbidden: User  
"system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot get resource "namespaces" in API group "" in the namespace "default"
```

I have given my user "owner"  role - so hopefully that is not the issue. But not sure how the CLI identifies the user and permissions (new to me). Also the kubectl -n flag does not work with helm (?)

Comment: RBAC is enabled and the correct permissions are not assigned. This answer should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54516778/8016720

Comment: Yes it worked, thx

Answer (score 0):

Most of documentation simply says just do `helm init` - but that does not provide any permissions to Tiller - so it would fail- unable to execute anything.
[Create Service account with cluster-admin role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54514994/not-able-to-create-prometheus-in-k8s-cluster/54516778#54516778)  using the rbac-config.yaml. 
Then helm init with this service account to provide permissions to Tiller

$ kubectl create -f rbac-config.yaml
serviceaccount "tiller" created
clusterrolebinding "tiller" created
$ helm init --service-account tiller